# How to Draw a line with custom widget and change the angle when user tap on line flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, line, flutter-animation

I am trying to change that line coordinate when the user taps on a view and draws a line.

I almost had success but got stuck the last point when the user taps on the line and tries to change the line coordinate the widget is not updating according to coordinates.

When the line is already drawn on the scene and try to combine with another line, the line is not showing and then the angles are not updating.

Code:-

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint( //                       <-- CustomPaint widget
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter { //         <-- CustomPainter class
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //                                             <-- Insert your painting code here.
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final pointMode = ui.PointMode.polygon;
  final points = [
    Offset(50, 100),
    Offset(150, 75),
    Offset(250, 250),
    Offset(130, 200),
    Offset(270, 100),
  ];
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 4
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
  canvas.drawPoints(pointMode, points, paint);
}
```

**Output:-**

[image: Screenshot]

**Want to achieve:-**

[image: Gif]

Can someone please explain to me how to draw a line and change the coordinate when user tap and pull the line and join the other line. I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even I'm stuck with this. Have you achieved the angle functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Gesture Detector to achieve this functionality. I used XGestureDetector https://pub.dev/packages/gesture_x_detector?  to change coordinates onTap.

```js
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return XGestureDetector(
      child: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            lastEventName,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      doubleTapTimeConsider: 300,
      longPressTimeConsider: 350,
      onTap: onTap,
      onDoubleTap: onDoubleTap,
      onLongPress: onLongPress,
      onLongPressEnd: onLongPressEnd,
      onMoveStart: onMoveStart,
      onMoveEnd: onMoveEnd,
      onMoveUpdate: onMoveUpdate,
      onScaleStart: onScaleStart,
      onScaleUpdate: onScaleUpdate,
      onScaleEnd: onScaleEnd,
      bypassTapEventOnDoubleTap: false,
    );
  }

  void onLongPressEnd() {
    setLastEventName('onLongPressEnd');
    print('onLongPressEnd');
  }

  void onScaleEnd() {
    setLastEventName('onScaleEnd');
    print('onScaleEnd');
  }

  void onScaleUpdate(ScaleEvent event) {
    setLastEventName('onScaleUpdate');
    print(
        'onScaleUpdate - changedFocusPoint:  ${event.focalPoint} ; scale: ${event.scale} ;Rotation: ${event.rotationAngle}');
  }

  void onScaleStart(initialFocusPoint) {
    setLastEventName('onScaleStart');
    print('onScaleStart - initialFocusPoint: $initialFocusPoint');
  }

  void onMoveUpdate(MoveEvent event) {
    setLastEventName('onMoveUpdate');
    print('onMoveUpdate - pos: ${event.localPos} delta: ${event.delta}');
  }

  void onMoveEnd(localPos) {
    setLastEventName('onMoveEnd');
    print('onMoveEnd - pos: $localPos');
  }

  void onMoveStart(localPos) {
    setLastEventName('onMoveStart');
    print('onMoveStart - pos: $localPos');
  }

  void onLongPress(TapEvent event) {
    setLastEventName('onLongPress');
    print('onLongPress - pos: ${event.localPos}');
  }

  void onDoubleTap(event) {
    setLastEventName('onDoubleTap');
    print('onDoubleTap - pos: ' + event.localPos.toString());
  }

  void onTap(event) {
    setLastEventName('onTap');
    print('onTap - pos: ' + event.localPos.toString());
  }

  void setLastEventName(String eventName) {
    setState(() {
      lastEventName = eventName;
    });
  }
```

In onMoveStart and onMoveEnd pass the selected value to achieve your result.